# How to correctly deploy an Angular Universal website to a specific path?

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment, bitbucket, devops

So, I have an app that is set up to be deployed through bitbuckets pipelines to a specific path e.g “website.com/path” but when I visit the site it tries to load the files on the root path “website.com/scripts.js”, so I have to ssh on the server and change the “base” on the index.html from “/“ to “/path/“ however doing it this way manually is very redundant and even the SSR is not working correctly.

P.S the site was originally deployed on the main root path “website.com” but a senior developer just told me “your website is now on 'website.com/path' and go change the paths on the pipeline to '/path/' ”, which I did.

**bitbucket pipleline:**

```
      - npm install
      - npm run build:ssr:stage
      - scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r dist/sns-angular xxxx@15x.xxx.xx.xx:/home/sco/www/website.com/new/sns-angular-new
      - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxxx@15x.xxx.xx.xx "cd /home/sco/www/website.com/new  && rm -rf sns-angular && mv sns-angular-new sns-angular"
```

**scripts:**

````
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng run sns-angular:serve-ssr",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr:stage": "ng build --deploy-url /sns-angular/ --base-href / && ng run sns-angular:server:stage",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run sns-angular:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/sns-angular/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run sns-angular:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run sns-angular:prerender"
  }```
````

Answer (score 2):

To set the base at build time, you have to adjust your `--base-href` in your `build:ssr:stage` script to e.g. `--base-href /my-path`.

To get SSR to work, you have to build your app with the `build:ssr` script (don't forget to add here your `--base-href`). After the build you should able to start the server with `serve:ssr` script which listen by default on port 4200.

Comment: how to specify assets ? I've used deploy-url /myPath/ and it's not working I'm receiving errors like:
```Unable to locate stylesheet: /var/www/html/dist/browser/myPath/styles.16d89a3cd69123f2ba9c.css```
because I'm not able to set the assets forlder correctly...

Comment: You can add your base href to your environments and prefix the assets with this path. At build time you can adjust this path, depending of which env you use. Can you provide a example repo? It would be easier to help you with that.

Comment: @RomanP. how should i prefix assets with the path?